# How to duplicate object "by value" in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I need to duplicate a product in my spree application. So

```
def my_duplicate_product(product)
  product.dup.tap do |new_product|
    new_product.slug = "#{product.slug}-#{rand(1000)}"
    ...
```

This code causes the original `product#slug` to be changed.

What am I supposed to do to get a copy of that particular product and leave the original unchanged?

Rails version: 4.0.3

**Update:**

The problem is not in Ruby, nor Rails — it's all about globalize gem (v. 4.0.0).

This error was fixed in 4.0.3.

It realy broke `#dup` so some values were "shared" between the original model and the duplicated one.

See GitHub issue tracker for more information: https://github.com/globalize/globalize/pull/352

Comment: But [doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Core/dup) says it copies only attributes..

Comment: You mean `dup` has the link to the _original_ object ?

Comment: dup gives me an object and its fields are linked to the original object's fields

Answer (score 1):

Maybe clone works:

```
def my_duplicate_product(product)
  product.clone.tap do |new_product|
    new_product.slug = "#{product.slug}-#{rand(1000)}"
```

[Clone method on ruby doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Object.html#method-i-clone)

Answer (score 0):

Update globalize gem to 4.0.3

See GitHub issue tracker for more information: https://github.com/globalize/globalize/pull/352